# Modelling - Creating Tripod Object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to make a city landscape but I can't figure out how to make those fancy rocks on the beaches. I've tried multiple things but they don't seem to work out well. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit - These are four conical sided rocks.

[image: These are four sided conical edged rocks]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some methods for a 4 studs shape:

**First method (Boolean):**

- Create a cylinder (12 vertices), put its origin to its bottom.
- Duplicate it with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Rotate the copy 120° (or whatever angle you need) on the Y axis.
- Duplicate the second cylinder and rotate it 120° on the Z axis.
- Again create a fourth cylinder and rotate it 120°.
- Now use some *Boolean* modifiers to merge these 4 cylinder.
- Remove doubles to make the final object clean. You should not have any vertices inside your mesh but if it happened just delete them.

[image]

**Second method (non-Boolean):**

1 - Create a cone of 3 vertices, Radius > 1, Depth > 1.5, it gives a 4 faces pyramid

2 - In Edit mode, select all the vertices, and bevel them with ctrl shift B

3 - Select the 4 hexagons of the shape

4 - Extrude the hexagons with alt E > Individual Faces

5 - You have a basic 4 studs shape

You can add a Subdivision Surface modifier, you can make each end round with W > Loop Tools > Circle, you can add Edge Loops, etc...

[image]

**Third method (better non-Boolean):**

1 - Create a cone of 3 vertices, Radius > 1, Depth > 1.5, it gives a 4 faces pyramid

2 - Subdivide each angle of the pyramid

3 - Select all the new vertices and scale up so that you have some kind of regular hexagons on each 4 faces of the shape

4 - Select all the faces and alt E > Extrude Individual

5 - Keep the end of each extrusion selected and W > Loop Tools > Circle

6 - You can add a Subdivision Surface modifier, can add Edge Loops, etc...

[image]

Comment: Neat. Now all that's left to do is make a few dozen, give 'em a bit of rigid body love, and see whether they interlock like the ones on the beach.

Comment: @moonboots I tried your method bit it doesn't look like the reference. In reference, all the four sides of the rock are intersecting without any spaces or gaps in them like a pipe joint. https://imgur.com/a/T1DenB2

Comment: Ashutosh, I've edited my post to propose another solution, I hope it fits your needs

Answer (score 3):

A lazy way to do this.

Enable the Add Mesh: Extra Objects
[image]

Add>Mesh>Mechanical Objects>Pipe Joints>Pipe Y Joint.

[image]

It will give you a base object like this:

[image]

Select the loop rings on the center and scale them.

[image]

Then extrude the outer edges and scale at will.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you also got confuse with the image. He says its 4 side not 3 side

Answer (score 1):

Start with the cylinder. <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd> add cylinder.

Rotate the cylinder to Y axis.

In the edit mode extrude one end of the cylinder and scale down.

Add one loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

In the edit mode move the mesh to get the pivot point edge of the cylinder.

Add <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd> add empty.

Select the mesh and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and select origin to 3D cursor.

Add a Array modifier from modifier tab. Increase the count 3 and select empty as object.

[image]

Finally adjust the shape and bevel the end with <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Atek, it's supposed to be a 4 sides shape, you've made a 3 sides shape

Comment: @moonboots look above in the reference image its 3 side

Comment: Actually these are for conical sided rocks. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: to me it's a 4 sides shape, anyway, here is a solution for 4 sides (in the 4th picture, just bevel the vertices with ctrl shift B), I don't know if it's the best though: https://www.zupimages.net/up/18/26/zgh4.jpg

Comment: @atek Actually I've visited this place and I know its a four-sided rock.

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo ok instead of 3 count u add 4 count. Nothing will change

Comment: @moonboots instead of 3 count add 4 count process will not change

Comment: Atek, it's not the same shape  ;)  consider it as a 4 face pyramid and each face has been extruded, that's why I used a 4 face pyramid as my initial shape, take a look at my method: https://www.zupimages.net/up/18/26/zgh4.jpg

Comment: @atek I tried adding 4 count in array but it doesn't seem to work out. It looks like a plus shape.

Comment: @moonboots I had tried the method you mentioned previously but it didn't work out since it does not merge all the four sides properly as in the reference. It leaves a bit of gap in between the four sides of the rock ;)

Comment: Second method explained in my post